# Using symbol parameters in a function without parentheses and quote in Common Lisp

Tags: common-lisp

```
(defun all-longer-than-1-char? (&rest elements)
  (every (lambda (x) (> (length
             (cond ( (typep x 'integer) (write-to-string x) )
                   ( (typep x  'string)  x )
                   ( (typep x  'symbol) (symbol-name x) )
                   ))
             1))
     elements))
(all-longer-than-1-char? "OK" "NO" 1)
```

I'd like this function to work on symbol parameters (i.e. without having to double quote or to enter numbers) but it doesn't work. To make it work with symbol parameters:

```
(defun all-longer-than-1-char? (lst)
  (every (lambda (x) (> (length
             (cond ( (typep x 'integer) (write-to-string x) )
                   ( (typep x  'string)  x )
                   ( (typep x  'symbol) (symbol-name x) )
                   ))
             1))
     lst))
(all-longer-than-1-char? '(OK NO 1))
NIL
```

But this time I have to enclose the parameters inside parentheses and quote it. I'd like to make it work both with symbol parameters and without having to put parameters inside parentheses and quote them, like:

```
(all-longer-than-1-char? OK NO 1)
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `&rest` to create what would once have been called a 'nospread' function (or an 'lexpr' depending on your religion), which is very often less useful other than as a user-interface since if you have a list of things you then have to use `apply`.

Common Lisp doesn't have functions which don't evaluate their arguments, which was once what was known as a 'nlambda' (or an 'fexpr' if you belong to the wrong cult), so you need to quote forms which would otherwise mean something to the evaluator.

You can get the same result as an nlambda with a macro.  But you almost certainly don't want to do that as it smells like a bad use of a macro.

Given

```
(defun all-longer-than-1-char-p (list)
  (every (lambda (x)
           (> (length
               (etypecase x
                 (string x)
                 (integer (write-to-string x))
                 (symbol (symbol-name x))))
              1))
         list))
```

Then the nospread one might be

```
(defun all-longer-than-1-char-p/nospread (&rest list)
  (all-longer-than-1-char list))
```

And the nlambda one might be

```
(defmacro all-longer-than-1-char-p/quoted/nospread (&rest things)
  `(all-longer-than-1-char ',things))
```

So now

```
> (all-longer-than-1-char-p '(xx yy 12 "foo"))
t

> (all-longer-than-1-char-p/nospread 'xx 'yy 12 "foo")
t

> (all-longer-than-1-char-p/quoted/nospread xx yy 12 "foo")
t
```

(All assuming `*print-base*` is less than `13`).

But

```
> (let ((x "xx"))
    (all-longer-than-1-char-p/quoted/nospread x))
nil
```

So, not very semantically useful, and kind of a poster child for how not to use macros.